# Why don't they just build smaller Jaegers?

Tags: pacific-rim

In Pacific Rim they need two pilots because the mental load of piloting a skyscraper sized Jaeger is too much for one person. But why don't they just make smaller Jaegers and double team the Kaiju? You don't need to depend on these quirky unreliable duos and can instead employ actually trained disciplined soldiers.

Comment: "Why don't you just make ten louder and make ten be the top number and make that a little louder?" "These go to eleven."

Comment: Ah...like raptors from Jurassic Park. Smaller. Meaner. Viciously Fast. Nothing wrong with the concept. Probably doesn't play well in the movie maker imaginations. But a gang of raptor mini-jaegers could be an impressive back-up team, or a story line all by themselves.

Comment: Why do you assume that the size of the Jaegers is what requires the shared neural load? There's nothing in the movie, book, or supplemental materials to support that idea.

Comment: The Jaegers are also all walking on the bottom of the ocean to get to the Kaiju. The Jaegars are only exposed from the waist up. A smaller unit, if possible, would likely be half the height and defeat the purpose of taking the fight to the spot they all emerge from (i.e. keeping them away from people)... The question I always asked is why not fly a nuclear tow missile through their mouth or eyes...

Comment: @phantom42 Actually in this video I'll link they say that the mental load of controling a mech *this size* is too much for one person. And the narration in the beginning of the movie says that each person acts as a hemisphere for the brain of the Jaegar, indicating that they are sharing the neural load of moving half the body. Thats what indicates to me that if the mech was just smaller one person could pilot it. They even show a clip from the movie of one guy controlling a jaegar arm alone without issue. https://youtu.be/2rGVxfP8n4U

Comment: Because that would be half as awesome. You know what would be four times as awesome? A double-sized super-Jaeger that the normal Jaegers need to fight for some reason.

Comment: Well that, is answered at the beginning of the movie. Quoting the narrator "To fight the monsters, we made our own." To fight a 100foot tall Kaiju, they sure were NOT gonna make a 20foot Jaeger. Simple! :)

Comment: I think Rule of Cool covers this question.

Comment: Controlling a simple single arm as a test was one thing, controlling an entire mech is another. The novelization explains that even the first Jaeger was too much for one person by themselves. No consideration of size of the jaeger is ever mentioned.

Comment: @phantom42 See I considered that but the first jaeger was apparently Brawler Yukon. If you play the pacific rim mobile game(I did for this very question) you'll see its about the same size as the others. The accuracy of the game is obviously questionable but from all other media where you can see it such as a the comic it still looks collossal. And yeah controlling one arm is probably easier but I don't really see why unless it has something to do with the size. How big can a mech be before your mind breaks? Can they not even pilot a powersuit?

Comment: What about a Jaeger 100x normal size that requires two normal-size Jaegers to pilot, each requiring two human pilots? By multiplicative property of awesomeness, that would be roughly 1000x more awesome.

Comment: @vynsane Don't forget the even bigger Jaegers piloted by two of those Jaegers.

Comment: @vynsane -They're saving that for the third film.

Comment: Smaller Jaegers? Ridiculous. Bigger Jaegers? [Also ridiculous](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71483/why-didnt-they-build-the-jaegers-twice-as-big-as-the-kaiju-to-crush-them-easily). The clearly-100%-sensible option is giant telepathically-controlled robots of the exact size we see in the movies.

Comment: because the writers didn't care about practicality, they only wanted awesome factor. The whole entire movie was just an excuse to watch giant mechs fight giant monsters. In reality, it would have been smarter just to use planes and bomb them with AtS missiles.

Answer (score 13):

Why does our current military build tanks which require more than one person to operate? Wouldn't more, smaller tanks be more effective? It's because the calculations indicate that a three or four-person crew will be more effective, in part because each can focus on their own responsibilities in a complex battlefield as opposed to each one worrying about each individual aspect of operations.

Will this equation change as technology advances? Undoubtedly. But that is the technology level where we are now. I expect the situation with the Jagers is similar- less to do with the actual size than the number of operations and responsibilities required to be juggled in mind all at once.

And the smaller= more effective in force only goes so far. There's a reason why the military also still has a multi-person crew manning an entrenched m60 rather than giving each person a pistol; in the right circumstances, it acts as a force multiplier to be greater than the sum of its parts, so to speak.

In other words: a smaller Jager does not substantially reduce the mental load on a pilot. The pilot must still track location, balance, weapon aiming, movement, limb coordination, etc. it may well be in in their future, many of these techs can be automated, but until that time it requires a team to reduce the mental strain. And if you need a team of two, and the number of pilots is limited, you would probably prefer to build a size that can go toe-to-toe rather than an intricate coordinated dance of a fight (in which you may end up harming your allies).

Comment: Good realistic reasons.  I think you're missing a (very) important factor on why they would do this.  **Costs!!!**  A 5-man tank (do tanks hold that many? I have no idea) would cost a lot less than 5 tanks of 1/5th size.  Manufacturing more smaller parts is definitely more expensive, let alone surface area considerations that mean you would require _more_ material to make 5 1/5th sized tanks.  Even if you only got 2.9 men's power from 3 men using a M60; there would be a point where they get better bang for the buck by grouping up.  Cost effectiveness is a big factor for large armies.

Comment: @JMac damn fine point you make, which I hadn't considered. When paying for skyscraper sized robots, you're going to need to look at bottom line considerations for getting the most bang for your buck.

Comment: @Broklynite
Funnily enough, both your and JMac's points are wrong! The military has been trying to minimize the crew size of tanks since their invention! In fact a tank can be effectively driven by 2 person crews with one guy driving and another guy manning the gun. Everyone else is just for redundancy and extra gunners. Also: its actually cheaper to build smaller vehicles. The main appeal of light tanks is exactly that you can produce them in bulk because they are cheaper to make. Thanks for the effort though!

Comment: @Elazertwist I think you misunderstand to a degree. I didn't say it's better to have more people, I said that they're using the minimum viable number, and that number decreases as technology advances. Technology is the greatest force multiplier. If two people can run a 2018 tank as opposed to a WWI tank, that's because the technology has progressed to allow them to do so. There's also a reason why we have tanks rather than just a fleet of APCs.

Answer (score 7):

In the prequel comic "Pacific Rim: Tales from Year Zero" - *(from now on "TYZ")*, this is actually addressed, to an extent.

The problem isn't the size of the Jaeger - after all, they aren't telekinetically moving it with their mind. It's the complexity of controlling it via the neural link.

This is why:

- Pentacost was able to control a single arm built early on as a prototype (TYZ page 46)
- Yet, the first test pilot (Captain Casey) had a seizure - as per Dr. Lightcap, "his motor cortex can't handle it"
- Also, the second test pilot for the demo (D'Onofrio) had a seizure when he tried to control the weapons (though he could move the Jaeger by himself). The technobabble term used was "Neural cascade" and "Neural load is too high". (TYZ pages 57-59)
- The conclusion was "The **tech** was too much for just one mind. It needed Two pilots". (TYZ page 60)

#### TL;DR: with the PONS neural link technology they had, controlling a Jaeger by one pilot wouldn't work even if it was smaller - it was a function of technology and complexity.

Comment: I actually mistook the first point (with Pentacost) as when he had to pilot the Jager alone, until I realised you mentioned it was an early on prototype.

Comment: Isn't this contradicted by Amara and Scrapper in Uprising? Scrapper's a smaller, single pilot Jager.

Comment: @Jontia - "they had" being the key word. Presumably, by the time of the sequel, the technology improved significantly from initial prototypes - remember they also had auto (pilotless) jaegers too. That, or they just pulled a "Highlander 2" and we should ignore the sequel as far as canon :P

Answer (score 2):

As of Pacific Rim Uprising we know that this would have been possible and that there is significantly more leeway in the two linked humans required to control a Jaeger 'rule' than is suggested in the first movie.

The first example of this is Amara's Jaeger Scrapper. It is very small by Jaeger terms with the wiki giving its height as just over 12 metres and weight as 278 tons. However, she is entirely able to control it on her own without any apparent ill effects.

Secondly, we have the Kaiju-Jaeger hybrids introduced later in the film. While it isn't made clear exactly how they work they don't seem to have dual operators unless these are sharing the same 'body'. If humanity had been able to understand and reverse-engineer the technology there would have been nothing stopping them from creating similar hybrid Jaegers.

As to why they didn't pursue this option, it could  be that bigger Jaegers were more efficient kaiju fighters, able to operate quicker and with easier logistics over long distances or could mount heavier weaponry. Also, the human commanders don't always make the best decisions as shown by the anti-Kaiju wall project.

Comment: Bigger Jaeger means bigger mass to throw at the meat (punches).

Answer (score -1):

Several reasons, I suspect. But these two are 'real life' (well, sort of) but might not fit in the Jaeger world.

1) The first would be, little guys just don't have the "cool" factor movie makers with $100 million budgets are looking for. Sort of like how Star Trek kept coming up with bigger and fancier Enterprises, then went backwards when writers say, why do we have flying cities? We don't need them to promote a plot. But the movies still went for "big" in Darkness. So in the end, it gets kiddies (and the young at heart) excited and has a 'wow' factor.

2) But, what about raptors from Jurassic Park? Smaller. Meaner. Viciously Fast. Nothing wrong with the concept. As said, how will this play in the movie maker imaginations? A gang of raptor mini-jaegers could be an impressive back-up team, or a story line all by themselves. The concept of "smaller but effective" works very well in big mining operations around the world. Sure the trucks and diggers are huge, but after a point, it seems to make more sense to make more of what works, instead of just bigger. The biggest thing is, as has been learned, when the Big One breaks, you have a problem. When one of the small ones breaks, just roll out another one. This takes us back to the money people. Little guys just don't stir the imagination, in the movies... they think.

Comment: Welcome to Sci-Fi/Fantasy Stack Exchange! Check out the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. While this is a fair answer for out-of-universe reasons (although it lacks sources), I think that the OP is looking for in-universe reasons.